# QWebView does not work on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qwebview, qwebkit

If I add `QT += webkit webkitwidgets` to my pro file on Ubuntu 13.10 and want to create a QWebView:

```
#include <QWebView>

QWebView* mWebView = new QWebView();
mWebView->load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

I get the following errors:

> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstapp-0.10
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstinterfaces-0.10
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstpbutils-0.10
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstvideo-0.10
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstbase-0.10
>
> :-1: error: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
>
> :-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How can I fix them?

Comment: Have you installed the `-dev` packages for those libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the `-dev` packages installed, the command to install them should be:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev
```